# Java time variable

Tags: java, date, time

Can someone show me how to create a time variable, I am having a hard time figuring this one out. Basically I want that let's say:

time1 = "7:00"
time2 = "12:00"

Then if user inputs an hour that is between this time1 and time2 period to perform certain action.

Enter time -> compare to see if it's in that period of time -> perform whatever

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Google not installed on your machine?  https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Comment: [Java Date Time Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html)  class represents a time of day, without any date component.  That seems to be the class you want to use here.

You can create `LocalTime` objects with `LocalTime.of`, and compare them with `isBefore` and `isAfter`.  Like this.

```
LocalTime sevenThirty = LocalTime.of(7,30);
LocalTime eightTwenty = LocalTime.of(8,20);
LocalTime nineOClock = LocalTime.of(9,0);

if(eightTwenty.isAfter(sevenThirty) && eightTwenty.isBefore(nineOClock)) {
    System.out.println("8:20 is between 7:30 and 9:00");
}
```

Comment: Usually best to define spans of time using Half-Open approach where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. So: `if( ! eightTwenty.isBefore( sevenThirty ) && eightTwenty.isBefore( nineOClock ) ) {`

Comment: I'm sure OP is capable of adapting this to whatever they actually require.